# how to write self join in laravel 7 as my php sql query

Tags: php, laravel

> This is my php sql code how to impliment it in laravel 7...please any one can help me about this....

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.ID,a.nm,b.nm as under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,'0') AS openingbalance,a.drcr,a.bankacno,
                                            a.bankifsccode,a.address,a.workphone,a.mobile,a.email,a.contactperson FROM maccountgroup a,
                                            maccountgroup b WHERE a.parent_id=b.ID AND a.GL='L' and a.ACTIVE='Y' AND b.natureid = 1 AND a.comp_code = '".$_SESSION['comp_code']."'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at how [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) work. What you're trying to do is a join with the same table.

And also take a look at how the [join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins) works on Laravel. So for your query, there are different ways to do it, here is an example:

```
DB::table('maccountgroup as a')
  ->join('maccountgroup as b', 'a.parent_id', 'b.ID')
  ->where('a.GL', 'L')
  ->where('b.ACTIVE', 'Y')
  ->where('b.natureid', 1)
  ->where('a.comp_code', $request->comp_code) 
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Sir... I have done with your code... :)

Comment: Sir I have got a error to execute the code can you help me that where I write wrong code in..
                       ->select(DB::raw('a.ID,a.nm,b.nm as under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,0) AS openingbalance,a.drcr,a.bankacno,a.bankifsccode,a.address,a.workphone,a.mobile,a.email,a.contactperson FROM maccountgroup a, maccountgroup b'))
                      ->get();

Comment: Isn't necessary to use that in a single DB::raw, only use DB::select("your query", your params). I'm not sure but give what error you're getting

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`nm` as `under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,0)`

Comment: from `maccountgroup` as `a` inner jo' at line 1 (SQL: select `a`.`ID,a`.`nm,b`.`nm` as `under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,0)` from `maccountgroup` as `a` inner join `maccountgroup` as `b` on `a`.`parent_id` = `b`.`ID` where `a`.`GL` = L and `b`.`ACTIVE` = Y and `b`.`natureid` = 1 and `a`.`comp_code` = 27)"

Comment: I hv wrote as....->select('a.ID,a.nm,b.nm as under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,0) AS openingbalance,a.drcr,a.bankacno,a.bankifsccode,a.address,a.workphone,a.mobile,a.email,a.contactperson FROM maccountgroup a, maccountgroup b')
                      ->get();

Comment: Do something like this: https://pastebin.com/jb03A46Q

Comment: Dear Sir can you saw above my PHP query ?? which I want to execute in laravel controller.. I am trying hard to execute the query ... please help me....thank you this is the query...$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.ID,a.nm,b.nm as under,IFNULL(a.openingbalance,'0') AS openingbalance,a.drcr,a.bankacno,
                                            a.bankifsccode,a.address,a.workphone,a.mobile,a.email,a.contactperson FROM maccountgroup a, maccountgroup b WHERE a.parent_id=b.ID AND a.GL='L' and a.ACTIVE='Y' AND b.natureid = 1 AND a.comp_code ='".$_SESSION['comp_code']."'");

Comment: Modified: https://pastebin.com/FAC3EX3Y

Comment: Sir I have got this error..."message": "Undefined variable: _session", and I have tried to use as session('comp_code'); and ther also got error as "message": "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given",... I am so sorry sir to disturbed you ... but I have trying to execute but fail ....

Comment: I guess you recibe a request, try with `$request->comp_code`

Comment: It depends of the way you receive the request

Comment: Yes sir I have a ajax request..